# Проверить доступность BlueTooth устройства

Tags: linux, bluetooth

В общем необходимо проверить. Если ли в зоне досягаемости определенное устройство.

Пробовал изначально так

```
sudo l2ping C7:E3:F4:BC:E6:8F
```

Но в ответ получаю. Хотя если искать девайс через интерфейс то его находит.

> Can't connect: Host is down

Может есть какие-то API чтоб это проверить или другие способы?

**Update**

В общем как понял девайс то LE(xiaomi mi band 2), видимо из-за этого не пингуется. Попробовал на телефоне поэксперементировать. Проходит как

```
sudo hcitool info 28:ED:6A:B5:FA:D4
```

Так и

```
sudo l2ping -c 1 28:ED:6A:B5:FA:D4
```

Кстати если так попробовать то получаю ошибку

```
sudo hcitool leinfo C7:E3:F4:BC:E6:8F
```

> Requesting information ...
>
> Could not create connection: Input/output error

Идеи предложения?

Comment: Да, это называется inquire. `hcitool inq`

Comment: @0andriy адрес я знаю. Оказалось что устройство Low Energy видимо из-за этого. Но как решить так и не нашел.